# Counterexample for simple statement

Tags: examples-counterexamples

I am refreshing my math skills by reading through one of my math books: [Mathematik](https://www.amazon.de/Mathematik-Tilo-Arens/dp/3642449182/), the second edition.

In Exercise 2.8, one question was if

$\forall (x,z) \in \mathbb{R}^2 \,\, \exists y \in \mathbb{R}:x\cdot y = z $

is a true statement. In the solution, it says it is not.

Can someone give me a counterexample, since I can not come up with one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: take $x=0$. What can you say about $x \cdot y$?

Comment: that $x \cdot y = 0$. Now i feel stupid... Thank you